# XmlClass parameter not passed to class on instantiation

Tags: java, testng

I'm trying to programatically launch TestNg tests something like this,

```
public class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Add parameter to XmlClass
        Map<String, String> testClassParameters = new HashMap<>();
        testClassParameters.put("classParam1", "valueOfClassParam1");
        testClassParameters.put("day", "Friday");

        XmlClass testClass = new XmlClass();
        testClass.setParameters(testClassParameters);
        testClass.setClass(TestClass.class);    

        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
        suite.setName("TmpSuite");

        XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
        test.setName("TmpTest");
        // Add parameter to XmlTest
        test.addParameter("testParam1", "clock");
        test.setXmlClasses(Arrays.asList(testClass)) ;

        TestNG tng = new TestNG();
        tng.setXmlSuites(Arrays.asList(suite));    
        tng.run();
    }
}

public class TestClass {

    @Test
    @Parameters({"day", "testParam1", "classParam1" })
    public void test1(String day, String testParam1, String classParam1) {
        System.out.println("Day: " + day);
        System.out.println("testParam1: " + testParam1);
        System.out.println("classParam1: " + classParam1);
    }
}
```

But the parameters set in the `XmlClass` is not being passed to the test method. Whereas it is being passed only if it is set from `XmlTest`.

Have couple of questions on this behaviour,

Is this expected? If so, why the class is being chosen from `XmlClass` but the parameters from `XmlTest`?

Given this behaviour, how can I pass different parameters to each classes without defining method parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Use **`ITestContext`**:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    @Parameters({"testParam1"})
    public void test1(ITestContext context, String testParam1) {
        Map<String, String> testClassParameters = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getClasses().get(0).getAllParameters();
        System.out.println("Day: " + testClassParameters.get("day"));
        System.out.println("testParam1: " + testParam1);
        System.out.println("classParam1: " + testClassParameters.get("classParam1"));
    }
}
```